# HashiCorp Vault OIDC SSO - Restricting Namespace Login Access to an Azure AD Group

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, openid-connect, hashicorp-vault, terraform-provider-vault

I have implemented an OIDC single sign-on solution for Vault, using Azure AD for user authentication. To date, it all works pretty well and myself and other users within my organisation are able to login to Vault successfully via Azure AD SSO.

Not everything though is working as expected and having tried all manner of changes in an attempt to get things working, I have simply run out of options. Sadly, the documentation available from the HashiCorp website and my endless online research have failed to yield any positive results too.

To date, I have an Azure AD app registered and configured successfully and I have also successfully provisioned and configured all of my core Vault resources using Terraform.

Also in Azure AD, I have a created a couple of groups - one for our Vault Admins and the other for our Vault Users, as depicted in the below image. Both groups are mapped to two Vault external groups.

[image: My Azure AD Groups]

In my Terraform code, I also have two OIDC auth method configurations, one mounted on the Root namespace and the other mounted on a child namespace. Below, I have provided a snippet of the terraform configuration for the Root namespace but not that of the child namespace, as frankly aside the odd name and/or reference change, they're almost identical and so the below example should be enough to provide adequate context.

/* OIDC auth method mounted on ROOT namespace */

```
    resource "vault_jwt_auth_backend" "root" {
      description = "OIDC single sign-on for the root namespace."
      oidc_discovery_url      = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${var.tenant_id}/v2.0" 
      path                    = "oidc"
      type                    = "oidc"    
      oidc_client_id          = var.client_id
      oidc_client_secret      = var.client_secret
      default_role            = "azure"

      tune {
         max_lease_ttl      = "90000s"
         listing_visibility = "unauth"
         #listing_visibility = "hidden"    
        }
        provider_config = {
          provider = "azure"
          fetch_groups = true
          fetch_user_info = true
          groups_recurse_max_depth = 1
        }
}  
  
    resource "vault_jwt_auth_backend_role" "azure" {
      role_name             = var.azure_role_name 
      backend               = vault_jwt_auth_backend.root.path
      user_claim            = "email"
      groups_claim          = "groups" 
      
      bound_claims          = { "groups": "VaultAdmins" }
      
      role_type             = "oidc"
      oidc_scopes           = var.oidc_scopes 
      allowed_redirect_uris = var.allowed_redirect_uris
      verbose_oidc_logging  = "true" 
  }
```

So now onto the issue we're facing?

If I was to comment out the `bound_claims` line in the `vault_jwt_auth_backend_role` configuration, all members of the two AD groups are able to log into Vault without any issues and completely unrestricted. This is however not how we intend to implement our solution.

What we wish to set up is to restrict access to the Root namespace to only members of the VaultAdmins Azure AD group, all other users being blocked from gaining access. The remaining users who'll all be members of the VaultUsers Azure AD group, will be restricted to the child namespace through a similar Terraform configuration, albeit with the appropriate settings.

With the current configuration, I keep getting the below error when attempting to login as a member of the VaultAdmins group. Other variations to the terraform configuration have likewise produced similar errors.

[image]

I'm inclined to believe that perhaps my `bound_claims` configuration is incorrect, but I simply cannot find any examples or help material to point me in the right direction. Any idea how I can get this working as desired?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below can be worked around:

**1.** Please check this [***blog***](https://stronglybranched.io/2020/06/azure-ad-oidc-auth-in-hashicorp-vault-using-terraform/#:%7E:text=Grant%20basic%20access%20with%20an%20OIDC%20role) on Azure AD OIDC auth in HashiCorp
Vault using Terraform which suggets that, ***to make use of the role
claims, set the `groups_claim to roles` instead of groups.***

*For example:*

```
    resource "vault_jwt_auth_backend_role" "azure" {
      backend        = vault_jwt_auth_backend.azure_oidc.path
      role_name      = "oidc"
    //  token_policies =””
    
      user_claim            = "email"
      role_type             = "oidc"
      allowed_redirect_uris = ["http://localhost:5790/oidc/callback",
     "…..vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback"]
      groups_claim          = "roles"
      oidc_scopes           = [" ", " "]
    
     // verbose_oidc_logging = true
    }
```

also try adding bound_claim if its the same issue .

or

**2.** Please check  if you're bound claims for groups is for  *list of
values* .If that’s the case one may need to update Vault to version
1.2 or later .For older versions you may have to  mount it as an external plugin i.e; you may need to build and register the latest
version of plugin in order  to get access.

```
Please try to define bound_claims as below 

    "bound_claims": { "groups": ["my-group"] }
```

**References:**

1. [vault oidc role mapping · Issue · GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-plugin-auth-jwt/issues/52)
2. [Add field to disable comma separation on `bound_claims`
   in `jwt_auth_backend_role` resource by vinay-gopalan ·  hashicorp/terraform-provider-vault · GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-vault/pull/1200)

Comment: Appreciate the feedback kavyasaraboju-MT. However, I have to make some key clarification - We're not using Azure Roles and so cannot set the groups_claim to "roles" as suggested. Our users are in Azure Groups only.  Also, the bound_claims definition and syntax you've proposed isn't compatible with Terraform, which is what we're using to provision and configure our OIDC auth method. In any case, I have tried this variation - bound_claims  = { "groups": ["my-group"] } -  and it's not worked, as I receive an Incorrect attribute value type error.

Comment: Another observation, I set my bound_claims along the lines of the following -> bound_claims  = { "email": "User1@my-email.com" } and that worked perfectly, as OIDC login was restricted to the specified email address only and all other login attempts with a different email address was denied. The take away from that meaning we can at least prove that the bound_claims argument works in certain scenarios but doesn't appear to do so on Azure AD groups.